# update multiple rows with same id

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables employeedetails and educationdetails

employeedetails

```
empid   name 
  1      xyz
  2      asd
  3      pqr
```

Now this empid is a foreign key in educationdetails

```
empid   qualification  Percentage
1          SSC             56
1          HSC             78
1          BE              55
2          SSC             80
2          HSC             67
2          BE              71
```

I want to update second table educationdetails like for empid 1 i want to change the marks of HSC from 78 to 80

how to do this as we are having 3 rows with same id

Comment: Also specify the expected table data after the update!

Comment: where is the primary key for `educationdetails` table? Still you can do with: `Update educationdetails set Percentage = 80 where empid = 1 and qualification = "HSC"`

Comment: do you have a query? or not anything at all yet?

Answer (score 0):

First define PRIMARY KEY to table `educationdetails`.

Use below query.

```
UPDATE educationdetails 
SET Percentage = 80 
WHERE empid=1 AND qualification = 'HSC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uniquely identify the column you want to update in the `educationdetails` table. So you will need to know the `empid` and the `qualification` of the row you want to amend.

```
UPDATE educationdetails 
  SET Percentage = 80 
WHERE empid=1 AND qualification = 'HSC'
```